# Unable to insert data in oracle sql using python

Tags: python, oracle, oracle11g, cx-oracle

I am trying to insert data into a table created in oracle sql using python. It temporarily inserts  data into the table but as soon as the python process ends , the data is deleted.

```
def submit_button(roll_no,name,marks):
    sql_query = 'INSERT INTO assignment_7 VALUES (:r,:n,:m)'
    c.execute(sql_query,[int(roll_no),name,int(marks)])
    c.execute('SELECT * FROM assignment_7')
    for rows in c:
        print(rows[0],'-',rows[1],'-',rows[2])
```

For example if (12,'aryan',20) are inserted into the table , the print statement works , but actually no data gets inserted when I check the table itself .

Name                      Null?    Type

---

ROLL_NO                   NOT NULL NUMBER
STUDENT_NAME                       VARCHAR2(30)
MARKS                          NUMBER

Answer (score 0):

try to  add  c.commit

```
def submit_button(roll_no,name,marks):
    sql_query = 'INSERT INTO assignment_7 VALUES (:r,:n,:m)'
    c.execute(sql_query,[int(roll_no),name,int(marks)])
    c.commit
    c.execute('SELECT * FROM assignment_7')
    for rows in c:
        print(rows[0],'-',rows[1],'-',rows[2])
```